# When a IClasspathContainer contains zero IClasspathEntry

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've built my own IClasspathContainer to link in a 3rd party JAR. On occasions no JAR can be found and getClasspathEntries return an array of zero IClasspathEntry objects.

The effect this has on the project tree is unexpected - the library/classpath-container vanishes from the project display *altogether*.

Ideally the library icon would remain in the project tree, leaving me something to decorate to indicate the error. More ideal still, I could decorate the root project icon to indicate a build error.

Can anyone advise how I might achieve this - if achievable at all?

M.